# How to make a new list by comparing values of two lists?

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = ['19', '17']
list2 = ['18', '19', '17', '20', '23]
```

Here `list1` size can be any length but not greater than the length of list2. The values will be one of from the `list2`. I want to make a new list from `list2` and `list1` like this.

```
list3 = ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0']
```

Here in `list3`, if values of `list1` matches the value in `list2` then it will become '1' else '0'.
Here `19` and `17` from list1 matches the values in `list2` so it replaced by '1' and other replaced by '0'.

Comment: So essentially you are counting the number of occurences of an integer from list2 that exists in list1? Shouldn't be too hard to start with some for loops....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an if else statement in list comprehension can achieve this

```
list1 = ['19', '17']
list2 = ['18', '19', '17', '20', '23']
             
list3 = [1 if i in list1 else 0 for i in list2] 

print(list3)
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Boolean to `int`, iterating each item from list2:

```py
>>> [int(v in list1) for v in list2]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

For better perfromance use `set` since it has *O(1)* complexity for membership check:

```py
>>> s = set(list1)
>>> [int(v in s) for v in list2]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list3 = [1 if obj in list2 else 0 for obj in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the list comprehension offers a shorter syntax when you want to create a new list based on the values of an existing list

```
list_one = ["252",  "252"]
list_two = ["252", "546", "253"]
[1 if i in list_two  else 0 for i in list_one]
```